# Classes arrays of objects value "nan"

Tags: c++

I have a problem when I execute the program,the results that I have got is "nan" for the values of vector.I do not exactly where is the mistake. the method distancias generates a correct value but the method variogram does not generate the expected value instead of that generates a value "nan".Sorry for my english.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

//this program is to calculate the kriging puntual 
using namespace std;

////
class Points{
    private:
        float x;
        float y;
    public:
        Points(float a,float b);
        Points();
        float distancia(float x_1,float y_1);
        float variogram(float h);
        float valor_1();
        float valor_2();
        void show(void);
};

Points::Points(){

}
Points::Points(float a,float b){
    x=a;
    y=b;
}
float Points::distancia(float x_1,float y_1){
    float d;
    d=pow(pow((x-x_1),2)+pow((y-y_1),2),0.5);
    return d;
}
float Points::variogram(float h){
    float v,c_0,c_1,a_1;
    v=c_0+c_1*(1.5*(h/a_1)-0.5*pow((h/a_1),3));
    return v;
}
void Points::show(void){
    printf("%.2f,%.2f\n",x,y);
} 
float Points::valor_1(){
    return x;
}
float Points::valor_2(){
    return y;
}


///////
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    float a_1,c_0,c_1;      //parameters of variogram
    float c,d;              // position of point to determinate
    float a,b;              //positions of all points except the point to      determinate
    int i=0,n;
    int j,k;

    Points final;           //point to determinate

    //this part is to enter the values of function sphere variogram

    printf("Enter the paramters of sphere variogram\n");
    printf("Enter the value of c_0: ");
    scanf("%f",&c_0);
    printf("Enter the value of c_1: ");
    scanf("%f",&c_1);
    printf("Enter the value of a: ");
    scanf("%f",&a_1);

    //determinating the postion of final point

    printf("Enter the position of the point to determinate: ");
    scanf("%f,%f",&c,&d);
    final=Points(c,d);
    final.show();


    printf("Enter the name of points for the krigeage: ");
    scanf("%i",&n);
    Points punto[n];
    float vector[n];
    do{
        printf("Enter the position x,y of the point %i: ",i+1);
        scanf("%f,%f",&a,&b);
        punto[i]=Points(a,b);
        punto[i].show();
        vector[i]=punto[i].variogram(punto[i].distancia(c,d));
        cout<<vector[i]<<endl;
        i=i+1;
    }while(i<n);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Why are you using `printf`/`scanf` in C++? You didn't even include `<cstdio>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the following function:

```
float Points::variogram(float h){
    float v,c_0,c_1,a_1;
    v=c_0+c_1*(1.5*(h/a_1)-0.5*pow((h/a_1),3));
    return v;
}
```

Here, you are declaring the local variables `v`, `c_0`, `c_1` and `a_1`. These values are not initialized, they can contain anything. However, it is not unlikely they actually are equal to zero. So when you calculate `h/a_1`, the result of that is probably plus or minus infinity. When you subtract two infinities with the same sign from each other, the result will be `NaN`.

What you should do is pass the values for `c_0`, `c_1` and `a_1` from `main()` to the function:

```
float Points::variogram(float h, float c_0, float c_1, float a_1){
    return c_0+c_1*(1.5*(h/a_1)-0.5*pow((h/a_1),3));
}

...

vector[i]=punto[i].variogram(punto[i].distancia(c,d), c_0, c_1, a_1);
```

Please compile your code with warnings enabled (if you use GCC, then use the `-Wall` command line option). Your compiler should then warn you about these uninitialized variables.